# javascript prototype get clicked element

Tags: javascript, onclick, prototype

I want to get the string from my 'data-text' field after I clicked on a string.

HTML:

```
<a onClick='Lightbox.open('http://www.google.com',16,9,95)' data-text='Hello World'>click</a>
```

Javascript:

```
var Lightbox;
$(function() {
    Lightbox = new Lightbox();
});
function Lightbox() {
    this.border = 5;
}
Lightbox.prototype.open = function(text,w,h,p) {
    $(this).attr('data-text'); // This line is not working **
}
```

How do I get to the anchor `<a>` element from within the "Lightbox.open" function? The `$(this)` inside this function represents the Lightbox class.

Comment: @adeneo How about just responding on my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
onClick='Lightbox.open('http://www.google.com',16,9,95, this)'
```

and change the signature to

```
Lightbox.prototype.open = function(text,w,h,p, anchor) {
```

Now refer to it by `anchor`

Comment: Thanks @Evan Knowles . This works, but if someone knows how to reach to the anchor from inside the "open" function, without giving extra parameters, that would be better for me.

Comment: @adeneo, what's your point here, is that a bad thing? Is it a cryptical way to tell me how to find the solution to my question?

Comment: @Jeroen Binding the click handler with jQuery would be easier then.